# PHP: Handling my passed array, insert and remove

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

An array creates by this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="0">Taxi
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="1">Bus
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[]" value="2">Train
```

Although the checkbox only comes if its true(if its checked), so only the checked checkboxes will be passed.

Now I am trying to do so that the checkboxes that gets passed(the ones that are checked), should insert a row in table `transports` and the checkboxes that are not checked(not gets passed) should delete. And if it already is inserted, it should not do anything.

So:

- Check if its already inserted before
- Insert new row in transports
  for the checkboxes passed
- Delete the
  rows for the checkboxes that didnt
  pass

I tried doing this:

```
    $transport = $_POST["transport"]; // variable receiving

    for($u=0; $u<3; $u++){ // taxi, bus and train (3)
         if($u == $transport[$u]){ 
            $alreadyExists = $connect->prepare("SELECT id FROM transport WHERE xID=:xID AND transport=:t");
            $alreadyExists->bindValue(":t", $u);
            $alreadyExists->bindValue(":xID", $cID);
            $alreadyExists->execute();
            $alreadyExists = $alreadyExists->rowCount();
            if($alreadyExists == 0){ // if it doesnt exists, insert into
          $updateTransport = "INSERT INTO transport (xID, transport) VALUES (:id, :t)";
          $updateTransport = $connect->prepare($updateTransport);
          $updateTransport->bindValue(":id", $cID);
          $updateTransport->bindValue(":t", $u);
          $updateTransport->execute();
            }
         }else{ // delete row as it is not checked
          $updateTransport = "DELETE FROM transport WHERE xID=:id AND transport=:t";
          $updateTransport = $connect->prepare($updateTransport);
          $updateTransport->bindValue(":id", $cID);
          $updateTransport->bindValue(":t", $u);
          $updateTransport->execute();
         }
    }
```

But It wont work properly, I receive undefined offset 2, 1 I cant figure out why

What have I done wrong? How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do somethign like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[tax]" value="1">Taxi
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[bus]" value="1">Bus
<input type="checkbox" name="transport[train]" value="1">Train
```

and

```
$toDelete = array('taxi'=>true,'bus'=>true,'train'=>true);  
foreach($_POST['transport'] as $k=>$v) {
  //> Insert $k

  $toDelete[$k]  = false;
}

foreach($toDelete as $k=>$v) {
   if ($v===true) {
    //> delete $k here
   }
}
```

Comment: @yes123 I dont understand, why is this better/ how does this work better than what i did? Where should I have the inserting and deleting part etc.?

Comment: For the inputs in HTML, I want to make them checked, if exists in the database, what would you recommend doing? a for loop checking?

Comment: @Karem: yes of course. always loop thru values. Don't write the same piece of code like in your question

Answer (score -1):

Check that the offset is defined.

`if(isset($transport[$u]) && ($u == $transport[$u])){`

Comment: The indices of `transport[]` are not predictable, you are better of just looping through them with a `foreach`, or `for($i = 0; $i < count($transports); $i++)` if need be.

Comment: @yes123 Yes you can, based on the value. The OP just wants to know why he is getting the undefined error. I do agree though that this is not the best way to do things.